# Angular: wait for data in the service

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have service in my Angular app, where I retrieve data form Firebase inside constructor, and assign them to variable.

```
  // AuthService

  public user;

  constructor(
    private fireStore: AngularFirestore,
    public fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
    this.fireAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    })
  }
```

And then I use it in component template:

```
// Component html

<div>{{authService.user?.firstName}}</div>
```

It work, but when page loaded div is empty, and receive data only after 1 second.

How can I fix this problem, and make data came instantly?

Comment: Use a resolver: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-resolve/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Resolver
  [Angular Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

and Also You can Change The code Segment As below

```
// Component html

    <div *ngIf="authService.user;then data_content else loading_content"></div>
    <ng-template #data_content>
      <div>{{authService.user.firstName}}</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #loading_content>
      <div>Loading ...</div>
    </ng-template>
```